# Syntax error in basic react-rails component

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-rails

Rails can't render a basic react component I've just started building out due to a supposed syntax error in one of my components. Thus far I haven't been able to figure out why this syntax is incorrect.

**Here is the error:**

```
ActionView::Template::Error (SyntaxError: unknown: Unexpected token (11:11)
   9 |   render () {
  10 |     return (
> 11 |       {this.renderMeetings()}
                  ^
  12 |     );
  13 |   }
  14 | ):
1: <h1>Events</h1>
2: 
3: <%= react_component('SearchContainer', {}, {prerender: true}) %>
4: 
5: <form action="/search_event" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get">
6:   <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search meetings"/>
```

**And here is the suspect component:**

```
class SearchResults extends React.Component {

  renderMeetings() {
   return this.props.meetings.map((meeting) => {
     return <SearchResultsPost meeting={meeting} />
   })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      {this.renderMeetings()}
    );
  }

}
```

***Any help you can provide is much appreciated!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{}` are required when you want to put some `javascript` code inside `html element`, since you are directly calling a function from `return` then `{}` are not required, if you use a `div` then you need to use `{}`, Write it like this:

```
render () {
    return (
      <div>{this.renderMeetings()}</div>
    );
}
```

or

```
render () {
    return (
       this.renderMeetings()
    );
 }
```

Comment: Whoops! Thanks for your quick response!